# Parse complete html page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I load a html with ajax. I want to load the result in a jquery object. I tried that but it returns null. How can I do this? I got a complete page including doctype, head elements and body elements.

```
var test = $(result); //result contains html code
alert(test.html()); //returns null
```

I load the data with this function.

```
function ajaxLoadContent(element) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "url to the page",
        type: "GET",
        timeout: 5000,
        datattype: "html",
        success: function(result) {
        //handler
        },
    });
    return false;
```

Comment: result is probably just a string

Comment: Can you show how you get the data into `result`? Also, does `alert(result);` show the html in the alert?  Just dumping html into a variable like that doesn't automatically make the .html() function return html.  your result variable may already be html.

Comment: Why not just print out the result? This should be text.

Comment: @Josh, added the function that call the page to the post. Yes the html is shown in the alert when i do `alert(result)`.

Comment: @WaiLam I want to do some modification before i use the html on my page.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's a while ago, but maybe you're still interested in it..

The intern implementation of `$(String)` is not able to build an jQuery object that contains `head` or `body` tags. It will simply ignore them and move all elements inside on level up.

So if your string is for example

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta ...>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="a"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

the resulting jQuery object will be an array of two elements

```
[<meta ...>, <div id="a" />]
```

to get a `body`-like jQuery object cut everything but the body content before passing it to jQuery:

```
body = '<div id="body-mock">' + html.replace(/^[\s\S]*<body.*?>|<\/body>[\s\S]*$/ig, '') + '</div>';
var $body = $(body);
```

now things work as expected.. for example

```
$body.find('#a')
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: why has this answer not been accepted? Save me from a lot of headache. Thanks!

Comment: why can't jquery parse the head and body?

Comment: Livesaver! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

test is just an html string, so you could simply do this to show the contents

```
alert(result);
```

and if you want to bind that to an element

```
$("#myDiv").html(result);
```

Comment: I want to be able to use some jquery functionality on the return value.

Comment: since result is just a string you will probably need to place it on the page before you can interact with it with jQuery.

Comment: Mzz than I need to place it in an hidden iframe I guess. That would be nasty. Probably better to design some out of the box solution.

Comment: Are you trying to load html and totally overwrite the html on the page? If so, why don't you just navigate to that page? ;)

Comment: Let me know exactly what you want to do with the HTML once it comes back and I might be able to help you out

Comment: Well i'm using Ajax for some of my functionality. I got a non JavaScript backup to support non JavaScript users as well. Both call the same url because I don't want to change my content twice when modifications are made. I guess best thing to do is to change my server side code that detects if this is a ajax call or not and modify the return value based on that.

Answer (score 1):

```
function ajaxLoadContent(element) {
$.ajax({
    url: "url to the page",
    type: "GET",
    timeout: 5000,
    datattype: "html",
    success: function(data) {
     var result = $(data);
    },
});
return false;
```

You should now be able to call the result like this (remember it's not added to the DOM yet):

```
alert(result.html());
```

Add to the DOM

```
result.appendTo("body");
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: No that doesn't work since the html i get contains head,body tags and even a doctype.

Comment: ok change it to:

var result = data;
$("html").html(result);

Let me know if it works?

Comment: I to have access to head elements aswell. This work's but only for body elements and the title element.

Answer (score -1):

Try the `load` method of jQuery object: http://api.jquery.com/load/

> Load data from the server and place
>   the returned HTML into the matched
>   element.

Comment: The author of this answer might be onto something. Converting the whole HTML string to a `data:` url and calling $.ajax() on it might just be the ONLY reliable method.