# why cant jquery find and return all html tags i.e. body/title

Tags: php, jquery

I have spent ages at this and dont understand why it is not working. I am using ajax to send a post to php curl which brings a url in it then goes back to ajax.  When I send an alert all the html of that page is displayed in the alert.  Now I want to use jquery to find each element i.e. body, h1, title and output the contents but when I do this it doesnt work for the body or title.  Why is that?

Here is my jquery

```
        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "senddom.php",
      data: {"dataString" : dataString },
      success: function(response) {   
  $('body').append("<p> contents of title:" + $(this).find('title').html() + "</p>");       
  $('body').append("<p> contents of all: " + $(this).find('body').html() + "</p>");

 $(response).find('h1').each(function() {
  $('body').append("<p> contents of H1: " + $(this).text() + "</p>");
});
```

this is my php

```
<?php 

    $site= $_POST['dataString'];             // get data
function curl_get($site){
    $useragent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$site);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

    $data=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;


}

function getdom($site){
    $html = curl_get($site);
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    @$xml->loadHTML($html);
    echo($html);


}

echo getdom($site);

?>
```

Comment: Well the `<title>` tag wouldn't be found in the `<body>` (it's in the `<head>`, or at least it should be in well formed HTML, the rest of this question is taking time to sink in for me though

Comment: I understand this but I am more concerned as to why the body isnt working because it isnt contained within an other element like the title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

inside your success block: `$(this)` -> `$(response)`

**Follow Up: Full text HTML vs Fragments**

While this may seem to take care of the immediate problem, it is dependent on whether or not your response is the full body HTML.

In this case, it seems as though `response` *is* the full text HTML.

The jQuery parseHTML method does not deal with full text HTML, and unfortunately `response` won't be parsed properly. Fore more info see: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js

In the case where you are looking to parse full text HTML, one approach would be to use the [DOMParser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser). It is worth noting that the support for parsing `"text/html"` is currently lacking; only available in Firefox. An alternative is `document.implementation` which has support in all but IE<9.

That said, an example in the case where you want to use `DOMParser` --

```
parser = new DOMParser();
doc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/html");
$response = $(doc)
$response.find('title').text()
```

An example in the where you want to use `documentation.implementation` --

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
var doc_el = doc.documentElement;
doc_el.innerHTML = response;
$response = $(doc_el); // 
$response.find('title').text()
```

For more information, I'll defer to a nice jQuery plugin (that deals with the x-browser support) that I found on github: [jquery.parsehtml.js](https://github.com/panzi/jQuery-Parse-HTML/blob/master/jquery.parsehtml.js).

Comment: thanks for your reply I have already done this and it brings back the same results comes back undefined still

Comment: umm.. what's response coming back as? the fulltext HTML?

Comment: in an alert it does come back as the full text html

Comment: ok. what results are coming back undefined? what does $(response).find('body') return?

Comment: can you throw the HTML thats coming back into pastebin?

Comment: it's a parsing issue... see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429851/parse-complete-html-page-with-jquery