# Parsing returned HTML from jQuery AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

What I'm trying to do seems simple:  get an *HTML* page through `$.ajax()` and pull out a value from it.

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/html",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#data').text(data);
            $('#wtf').html($(data).find('#link').text());
        },
        data: {
            html: '<!DOCTYPE html><head><title><\/title><link href="../css/popup.css" rel="stylesheet" /><\/head><body><ul><li><a id="link">content<\/a><\/li><\/ul><\/body><\/html>'
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that *jQuery* refuses to parse the returned HTML.

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcrM8/1/) I'm play with this in isn't working in the mean time, so there's little else I can do to provide a working example.

**UPDATE:** My [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtfsven/ywVKT/1/) is working fine, but it seems the problem is that in my actual project I'm trying to parse a large, complex bit of HTML.  Is this a known problem?

Comment: You need to use POST when using `/echo/html/` on jsFiddle (note the trailing slash, too).  http://jsfiddle.net/hcrM8/6/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your code works fine.  You just aren't using jsFiddle's API correctly.  Check the docs for `/echo/html/` (http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html#html):

> URL: /echo/html/
>
> Data has to be provided via POST

So, you need to update your AJAX call to use POST.  Also the trailing slash is needed.

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/html/",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#data').text(data);
            $('#wtf').html($(data).find('#link').text());
        },
        data: {
            html: '<!DOCTYPE html><head><title><\/title><link href="../css/popup.css" rel="stylesheet" /><\/head><body><ul><li><a id="link">content<\/a><\/li><\/ul><\/body><\/html>'
        }
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/hcrM8/6/

Comment: Then the problem must lie in the actual HTML I'm fetching in my project.  It's very large and very complex.  The thing is, if jQuery can parse the page when it exists within the page, why can't it parse the page returned from the AJAX request?

Comment: @wtfsven: What happens on your *real* page?  What do you see?  Any errors?  When doing `$(data)`, jQuery strips out the `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags.  Your jQuery object looks like: `[<title>, <link>, <ul>]`.  Is the HTML on your real page valid?  You may also need `.filter` vs. `.find` depending on its structure.

Comment: Ok, so it turns out for some reason jQuery is finding one iframe (that's what i'm selecting for), and not another.  I'm still looking into it, but it seems to be working for the time being.

Comment: It's old, but I comment because it's the top voted answer and the problem  hopefully is solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12848798/2590616

Comment: @RocketHazmat - `.filter` vs `.find` was all I needed. You don't know what you don't know.  Thanks mate! :)

Answer (score 8):

If you would like to parse it, **jquery** has a nifty trick :)

```
 ParsedElements = $(htmlToParse);
 Console.log(ParsedElements);
```

You now have `DOM` elements you can traverse without placing them in the body of the document.

Comment: But that's just the problem.  It's not parsing the HTML at all. `$('#wtf').html($(data).find('#link').text());` should return "content", but it's saying `text()` is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

> jQuery.parseHTML()
>
> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/

```
str = "hello, <b>my name is</b> jQuery.",
  html = $.parseHTML( str ),
  nodeNames = [];

// Gather the parsed HTML's node names
$.each( html, function( i, el ) {
  nodeNames[ i ] = "<li>" + el.nodeName + "</li>";
});
```

Some thing is wrong with your ajax on fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hcrM8/5/

```
var html= '<!DOCTYPE html><head><title><\/title><link href="../css/popup.css" rel="stylesheet" /><\/head><body><ul><li><a class="disabled" id="link">content<\/a><\/li><\/ul><\/body><\/html>';
            h = $.parseHTML(html);
            $('#data').text(h);
            $('#wtf').html($(h).find('#link').text());
```

Comment: This returns an array of elements.  I need a jQuery object that I can use selectors on.  (your fiddle returns null)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use the load method?

```
$( "#wtf" ).load( "/echo/html #link" );
```

Or, here's your fiddle fixed and working:

http://jsfiddle.net/hcrM8/4/

Comment: Because that's not what I'm doing in my project.  I'm reaching out to grab a page, pull some data from it, then throwing it away.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i fixed encapsulating requested html code into just one container element.

Bad Example:

```
<a href="link">Linkname</a>
<p>Hello world</p>
```

Jquery couldnt convert this to element, because it wishes to convert a single element tree. But those are not having a container. Following example should work:

Right Example:

```
<div>
    <a href="link">Linkname</a>
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All answers do not point to the real problem, jQuery seems to ignore the head and body tag and creates an array of nodes. What you normally want is, extract the body and parse it.

Take a look at this helpful answer, I do not want to copy his work:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12848798/2590616.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem, and it is not because you are doing something wrong.

it's because the "link" tag is not supposed to have any innerHTML returned, it's explicitly excluded in jquery, you will find some where this line:

```
rnoInnerhtml = /<(?:script|style|link)/i,
```

This tag in HTML is supposed to link to external style sheet.

Comment: He's not getting the `link` tag. He's getting the `a` tag with id: `#link`.