# Javascript regex to get the href attribute data from a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have been working with ajax and I have retrieved some data, I want to extract a url from an href attribute, with specific class name. I need a javascript regex for it to extract me the url from that bunch of data. The URL from that data should look like this.

**https://www.facebook.com/username**

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMpvo.png), this image shows the data, and its specific class name and the url in the href, I want to extract that url, fro, through that specific class name. The class name is : **class="_2s25 _606w"**

Comment: `$(data).find('._2s25 _606w').attr('href');`. check here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007721/parsing-returned-html-from-jquery-ajax-request

Comment: Why are you so [hell-bent on getting the username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090091/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-of-the-ajaxed-page), when Facebook does not want you to have access to that any more?

Comment: I am building an extension for that I need it CBroe

Comment: Thanks @AlivetoDie it worked

Comment: don't rely on `_2s25 _606w` type of classes, as they autogenerated and change almost on every new facebook build

Comment: so what can be a good solution for it @igormilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution : `$(data).find('._2s25 ._606w').attr('href');.`

Reference:- [Parsing returned HTML from jQuery AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007721/parsing-returned-html-from-jquery-ajax-request)